# How can I express this algorithm through summation

Tags: summation, algorithms, asymptotics

I have the following algorithm and I want to find Big-Oh but how can I express this series in summation form:

```
func()
{
    i=1; s=1;
    while(s<=n)
    {
        i++;
        s = s + i;
        print("something");
    }
}
```

$\qquad\begin{array}{c|cccccccc}
i & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & . . . & k \\
\hline
s & 1 & 3 & 6 & 10 & 15 & 21 & ... & n
\end{array}
$

By following the series above I can see $i = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ and $s_{i} = n$:

$\frac{k(k+1)}{2} > n => O(\sqrt{n})$

How can I write this in summation form:

$$\sum_{s=1}^{n}of what$$

Comment: You mean $S=\frac{k(k+1)}{n}$? You can write $S = \sum_{i=1}^n i$. That is what your sum is.

Comment: @bames, you can see from the table and algorithm that $i$ is growing in the $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ and $S$ has another way of growing which I can't define.

Comment: No. You can see from your table that for $i=k$, $S=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ for all values you have explicitly listed. I made some typos in my original comment, but $S = \sum_{i=1}^k i$, which is what I meant.

Comment: Yes you are right, but this one leads me on $O(n^2)$ and the complexity is $O(\sqrt{n})$

Comment: $k$ and $n$ are different. $k$ is roughly counting the number of loops you go through. Your loop stops when $\frac{k(k+1)}{2} > n$, so your program will stop in $O(\sqrt{n})$ time.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing the variable names in your question, but:

You are summing up values of $i$ from $1$ to $n$, so

$$S = \sum_{i = 1}^{k}i$$

which has the explicit formula $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ as you say.

Comment: How can I find from this $O(\sqrt{n})$

Comment: $k$ grows as $\sqrt n$ as you've stated, but there's no way of going from that to the specific summation formula. There are infinitely many sums that would have the same relationship.

Comment: So this is the only way of solving this problem?